# advice on listing site updates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to list latest updates on my site. I have 2 tables Books and Notebooks.

```
@books = Book.find(:all, :order => 'created_at', :limit => 3)
@notebooks = Notebook.find(:all, :order => 'created_at', :limit => 3)
@updates = (@books + @notebooks).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

view

```
<% @updates.each do |update| %> 
<%=update.created_at %> #i want to print type of update in here
<% end %>
```

how can i print type of update? can i add type value to instance variable like that?

```
@books.merge(:type => "book") #not working
```

my final view have to be like that:

```
10/10/2010 book added.
9/10/2010 notebook added.
```

Comment: If you need to do a lot of stuff like this, you might want to consider STI if the models are similar enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the class name

```
<%= update.class.name.downcase %>
```

Maybe best if you wrap it in a helper method, that way you can work with a case structure and expand it when new options are added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @updates.each do |update| %> 
  <%= update.created_at %>
  <%= update.class.to_s.downcase %> added.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Beat to it by Adam Lassek. :)